# How do I change observations in SPSS?

Tags: spss

Example:
In this dataset I want DH to be D3 and CR to be C2. I've tried googling if there is syntax for this but I can't find it. The actual data set I'm working with is much larger and has more variables that need to be changed.

--IDs--

C1

C2

D1

D2

D3

DH

CR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution. The recode command can be used for this.